# 2 Nested queries from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

So I have 3 tables

User Table

```
UserId User
```

Language Table

```
LanguageId Language Fluency
```

User Language Table

```
UserLanguageId UserId LanguageId
```

Basically what I need is a query where PriLang would be where Fluency='Primary' and SecLang is Fluency='Secondary' and looks somethin like this

```
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| User       | PriLang         | SecLang   |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Jimbo      | English         | Spanish   |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Norm       | French          | Spanish   |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| Kathy      | Japanese        | Italian   |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, the most straightforward approach involves two joins to the user_languages table, as well as a join to the langauges table for each of them.

```
select  usr.User, lg1.Language PriLang, lg2.Language SecLang 
from users usr
 left join user_languages ul1
  on ul1.userId = usr.userId
   and ul1.Fluency='Primary'
 left join user_languages ul2
  on ul2.userId = usr.userId
   and ul2.Fluency='Secondary'
 left join languages lg1
  on lg1.languageId = ul1.languageId
 left join languages lg2
  on lg2.languageId = ul2.languageId
```

Comment: Thanks, works exactly as intended. I didnt know you could have Fluency condition under ul2 like you have it there.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

One option uses conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    u.user,
    max(case when l.fluency = 'Primary' then l.language end) as pri_lang,
    max(case when l.fluency = 'Secondary' then l.language end) as sec_lang
from users u 
left join user_languages ul on ul.user_id = u.user_id
left join languages l on l.language_id = ul.language_id
group by u.user_id, u.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this depending on your setup; this should get you close using a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT u.User,
       (SELECT lt.Language
        FROM Language_table lt
            JOIN UserLanguage_table ult ON lt.LanguageId = ult.LanguageId 
            JOIN User_table u ON ult.UserId = u.UserId
        WHERE lt.Language_Fluency = 'primary'
            AND ult.UserId = u.UserId
            AND lt.LanguageId = ult.LanguageId) AS primary_lang,
       (SELECT lt.Language
        FROM Language_table lt
            JOIN UserLanguage_table ult ON lt.LanguageId = ult.LanguageId 
            JOIN User_table u ON ult.UserId = u.UserId
        WHERE lt.Language_Fluency = 'secondary'
            AND ult.UserId = u.UserId
            AND lt.LanguageId = ult.LanguageId) AS secondary_lang
FROM User_table u;
```

Comment: This will not return the correct results. You have to correlate the in-line query to the user as in `WHERE Language_Fluency = 'Primary' and userID = u.userID`

Comment: thanks for that; for my benefit in understanding correlated subqueries do we have to link the other 2 tables in the `WHERE` clauses or just the single like you have it?

Comment: @tlk27: Infact just remove the entire join clause and use inside the inline query with reference to user_id and other filters.

Comment: @tlk27:  just want to update you, some changes to the query I would suggest, 1. Language_table can be taken only once inside the inline query 2. When we have inline query as column we don't need left join instead simple join is enough because if join condition is matches it returns result or else null.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Thanks for your knowledge and suggestions. I appreciate you taking the time to provide the information and insight necessary to improve this solution